# Hibernate batching operation not working as expected

Tags: database, hibernate, postgresql, orm

I have a Person class with the following fields-

> id, hashedId, description

id is the primary key generated by a sequence and hashedId is Not Null.

I do the following:

> 1. session.saveOrUpdate(person)
> 2. person.setHashedId(hash(person.getId()))

The Id is autogenerated in the DB. When I do this, shouldnt I expect only 2 statements

> 1. Select to get the next sequence Id (person id)
> 2. Insert to insert the person record?

However, It is trying an insert right after step 1(during final transaction commit, ofcourse) with null hashedId - I get back a constraint violation error - HashedId cannot be null.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `Session.save()` or similar, Hibernate will immediately generate IDs and do the insert rather than simply queueing it up to be saved later. So there's no gap in which the element has its ID assigned before it's inserted. For the 'identity' ID generation strategy, it's completely impossible to split these up anyway...

In my experience, the safest and simplest way to handle this kind of case is to use an Interceptor (or maybe an EventListener?) to trap the entity being inserted with the hashedId property unset, and generate it just before the save. It's a bit unpleasant, but IMHO better than pulling ID generation up into the application code.

Here's an example where I generate the 'reference' property of a new Ticket entity (using an Interceptor):

```
public boolean onSave(Object entity, Serializable id, Object[] state, String[] propertyNames,
    Type[] types) {
    boolean changed = super.onSave(entity, id, state, propertyNames, types);

    if (entity instanceof Ticket) {
        for (int i = 0; i < propertyNames.length; i++) {
            if (propertyNames[i].equals("reference") && state[i] == null) {
                state[i] = generateTicketReference((Integer) id);
                changed = true;
            }
        }
    }

    return changed;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Hibernate is doing the right thing :-) See http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/mapping.html#mapping-declaration-id , section "5.1.4.4. Identity columns and sequences"

That's because Hibernate doesn't knows about the ID if it's generated by the DB. And the ID is not really assigned to a record just because you called a sequence. So, you should either let Hibernate save the record and retrieve the actual ID for the record, or you should use a Hibernate-generated ID (like hilo) (or generate it yourself,  with generator type "assigned").

Answer (score 0):

The HashedId field is derived from the ID, right? based on an inexpensive function, I assume? So in this case do you really need to persist that field in the DB? Do you use it directly in queries?
Can't you just have the getHashedId() method always return hash(this.id)? This way you won't have that hashedId field in the DB and you won't have to manage it - as it's simply deduced based on the id.

Hope this helps.